# How can I access my Google Drive files from Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I downloaded images from a url using `urlretrieve` (`urllib`) in Google Colab. However, after downloading the images, I am not able to locate the images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)

root_dir = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/"
base_dir = root_dir + 'my-images/'
```

Now you may access your Google Drive as a file system using standard python commands to read and write files. Don’t forget to append `base_dir` before root path(s) where you need to use. Here the `base_dir` variable expects a folder named `my-images` at the location pointed by `root_dir`.

[image]
[image]

Google Colab lets you access and use your Google Drive as a storage for a time constrained runtime session. It is **not** a disk storage on your local machine or physical computer. Notebooks run by connecting to virtual machines that have maximum lifetimes that can be as much as 12 hours.

Notebooks will also disconnect from VMs when left idle for too long which in turn also disconnects your Google Drive session. The code in the answer only shows one of many ways to mount your Google Drive in your colab runtime's virtual machine.

For more documentation, refer to this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) and [faq](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html).

Comment: where is "content" ? On my location machine or is it a virtual machine that we get with collab account. If it is my local machine it seems like a linux path. How is windows drive specified in the path?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, your working Google Drive Folder is

**Colab Notebooks/STUDY/**

Its actual path is **drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/STUDY**

1) First mount and authenticate yourself with the following code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2) Second change your current folder to point working folder STUDY

```
os.chdir("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/STUDY")
os.listdir()
```

Done!